# Interpolate Temperature Data On Urban Area Using Cartopy

Tags: python, matplotlib-basemap, qgis, cartopy, metpy

I'm trying to interpolate temperature data observed on an urban area formed by 5 locations. I am using cartopy to interpolate and draw the map, however, when I run the script the temperature interpolation is not shown and I only get the layer of the urban area with the color palette. Can someone help me fix this error? The link of shapefile is

https://www.dropbox.com/s/0u76k3yegvr09sx/LimiteAMG.shp?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yxsmm3v2ey3ngsp/LimiteAMG.cpg?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/yx05n31dfkggbb6/LimiteAMG.dbf?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/a6nk0xczgjeen2d/LimiteAMG.prj?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/royw7s51n2f0a6x/LimiteAMG.qpj?dl=0

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7k44dcl1k5891qc/LimiteAMG.shx?dl=0

Data

```
        Lat   Lon       tmax
 0   20.8208 -103.4434  22.8
 1   20.7019 -103.4728  17.7
 2   20.6833 -103.3500  24.9
 3   20.6280 -103.4261   NaN
 4   20.7205 -103.3172  26.4
 5   20.7355 -103.3782  25.7
 6   20.6593 -103.4136   NaN
 7   20.6740 -103.3842  25.8
 8   20.7585 -103.3904   NaN
 9   20.6230 -103.4265   NaN
 10  20.6209 -103.5004   NaN
 11  20.6758 -103.6439  24.5
 12  20.7084 -103.3901  24.0
 13  20.6353 -103.3994  23.0
 14  20.5994 -103.4133  25.0
 15  20.6302 -103.3422   NaN
 16  20.7400 -103.3122  23.0
 17  20.6061 -103.3475   NaN
 18  20.6400 -103.2900  23.0
 19  20.7248 -103.5305  24.0
 20  20.6238 -103.2401   NaN
 21  20.4753 -103.4451   NaN
```

Code:

```
import cartopy
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from matplotlib.colors import BoundaryNorm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader

from metpy.calc import get_wind_components
from metpy.cbook import get_test_data
from metpy.gridding.gridding_functions import interpolate,      remove_nan_observation 
from metpy.plots import add_metpy_logo
from metpy.units import units

to_proj = ccrs.PlateCarree()


data=pd.read_csv('/home/borisvladimir/Documentos/Datos/EMAs/EstacionesZMG/RedZMG.csv',usecols=(1,2,3),names=['Lat','Lon','tmax'],na_values=-99999,header=0)


fname='/home/borisvladimir/Dropbox/Diversos/Shapes/LimiteAMG.shp'
adm1_shapes = list(shpreader.Reader(fname).geometries())


 lon = data['Lon'].values
 lat = data['Lat'].values
 xp, yp, _ = to_proj.transform_points(ccrs.Geodetic(), lon, lat).T


 x_masked, y_masked, t = remove_nan_observations(xp, yp, data['tmax'].values)

 #Interpola temp usando Cressman
tempx, tempy, temp = interpolate(x_masked, y_masked, t, interp_type='cressman', minimum_neighbors=3, search_radius=400000, hres=35000)
temp = np.ma.masked_where(np.isnan(temp), temp)

levels = list(range(-20, 20, 1))
cmap = plt.get_cmap('viridis')
norm = BoundaryNorm(levels, ncolors=cmap.N, clip=True)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 10))
view = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=to_proj)

view.add_geometries(adm1_shapes, ccrs.PlateCarree(),edgecolor='black',  facecolor='white', alpha=0.5)


view.set_extent([-103.8, -103, 20.3, 21.099 ], ccrs.PlateCarree())

ZapLon,ZapLat=-103.50,20.80
GuadLon,GuadLat=-103.33,20.68
TonaLon,TonaLat=-103.21,20.62
TlaqLon,TlaqLat=-103.34,20.59
TlajoLon,TlajoLat=-103.44,20.47

plt.text(ZapLon,ZapLat,'Zapopan',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(GuadLon,GuadLat,'Guadalajara',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(TonaLon,TonaLat,'Tonala',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(TlaqLon,TlaqLat,'Tlaquepaque',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())
plt.text(TlajoLon,TlajoLat,'Tlajomulco',transform=ccrs.Geodetic())

mmb = view.pcolormesh(tempx, tempy, temp,transform=ccrs.PlateCarree(),cmap=cmap, norm=norm)
plt.colorbar(mmb, shrink=.4, pad=0.02, boundaries=levels)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! I have the same problem with cartopy. 
Could you plot only inside shapefile?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the call to MetPy's `interpolate` function. With the setting of `hres=35000`, it is generating a grid spaced at 35km. However, it appears that your data points are spaced much more closely than that; together, that results in a generated grid that has only two points, as shown as the red points below (black points are the original stations with non-masked data):

[image: Map with station and grid point locations]

The result is that it only creates two points for the grid, both of which are outside the bounds of your data points; therefore those points end up masked. If instead we set `hres` to something much lower, say 5km (i.e. `5000`), then a much more sensible result comes out:
[image: More sensible interpolation]